# Handling multiple conditions and wanting more than one outcome

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this problem with handling the conditions.

I understand that if I use the following `{stats?.[itemDate] > 0 && listings.length > 0}` as long as BOTH stats?.... and listings... return a result of 1 or more, it will return true.

However, what if I want another alternative condition, whereby if `listings.length = 0` it will also return true

What is the cleanest approach to achieve this?

Is there an inline solution to this?

**EDIT**

sorry I got myself confused while trying to explain the outcomes. What I really meant to say is if

`stats?.[itemDate] > 0 and listings.length > 0` ….true

`stats?.[itemDate] > 0 and listings.length == 0` ….. false

`stats?.[itemDate] == 0 and listings.length == 0` …. false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested ternary operator for this

```
{listings.length == 1 ? 1 : stats?.[itemDate] > 0 && listings.length ? 1 : 0}
```

if you need either or to be true then you could just use the OR operator

```
{stats?.[itemDate] > 0 && listings.length || listings.length == 1}
```

**EDIT**

if you need to check for both conditions then you can do it like so:

```
{stats?.[itemDate] && listings.length > 1 || stats?.[itemDate] && listings.length}
```

I added a check to see if the length of listings is greater than 1 here because if you were just checking `listings.length` on the left side then the statement would always be true for listings.length > 0 and it would never check if listings is == 1.

But if you are just checking whether `stats?.[itemDate]` is not 0 and `listings` is greater than 0 then just do:

```
{stats?.[itemDate] && listings.length}
```

Comment: What if I need `stats?.[itemDate] > 0` on both sides? Could I just write `{stats?.[itemDate] > 0 && listings.length || stats?.[itemDate] > 0 && listings.length == 1}`

Comment: Yes you can do that.  I have added an edit to my answer because the way you have it in your response it would always be true for the left hand side and never check the right.  Might i ask why you need to check if listings is > 0 and == 1?  Seems a little redundant to check it this way.

Comment: Sorry I think I got myself confused with the outcomes. Basically I have this function that enables an indicator if the check returns true. 

The conditions that need to be checked are the depending on the returns of `stats?.[itemDate]` and `listings.length` whereby, if

`stats?.[itemDate] > 0 and listings.length > 0` ….true

`stats?.[itemDate] > 0 and listings.length == 0` ….. false

`stats?.[itemDate] == 0 and listings.length == 0` …. false

Comment: Ok, i've updated my answer but the last implementation should get you what you are looking for.